# How do I create a variable in Google Tag Manager with custom JavaScript to convert another GTM variable date to ISO 8601 format?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, iso8601

I am trying to use Google Tag manager to create an Event schema markup dynamically and convert a (dynamic) date value on the page, which is specified in Google Tag Manager as a CSS Selector. The dates are in the following format:

`Saturday, October 20`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated; thank you in advance.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one GTM variable (let's call it "Original Date") in "Weekday, Month Date" format, you should be able to create a new variable, based on a javascript function, like this:

```
function() {
  var d = new Date({{Original Date}});
  return d.toISOString();
}
```